# IBM Watson Assistant: How can I send an image as chatbot response

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-storage

I want to attach an image as IBM Watson Assistant response.

It must be placed in a public repository, but I want to know if it is possible to have it on IBM Cloud Object Storage because I have my images there.

If I could not make it possible. How can I send an image as response in watson assistant? I could not find anything in the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-index).

Answer (score 1):

You can define [image responses in Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json#dialog-responses-json-image). This can be done either through the dialog builder or by using the JSON response editor. When using the dialog builder, [there is a form for the image title, description and the URL](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#api-dialog-responses-image).

To access an image on IBM Cloud Object Storage from within Watson Assistant and to display it, the image needs to be publicly accessible. You can either [enable public access on the entire bucket or on individual storage objects](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-iam-public-access). The first could be a security concern, the latter is more work.

The URL for the image would be composed of the public endpoint, the bucket and the image name, e.g., https://s3.eu.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/your-bucket-name/this-is-the-image.png.

Here is how in my test it looks in the **Try it out** window with the image coming from my public IBM COS bucket:

[image: Watson Assistant showing image response]

Comment: The instructions have been improved: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-multimedia-add